# Truncating a collection using Linq query

Tags: linq, lambda

I want to extract part of a collection to another collection.
I can easily do the same using a for loop, but my linq query is not working for the same.
I am a neophyte in Linq, so please help me correcting the query (if possible with explanation / beginners tutorial link)

Legacy way of doing :

```
Collection<string> testColl1 = new Collection<string> {"t1", "t2", "t3", "t4"};
Collection<string> testColl2 = new Collection<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < newLength; i++)
{
    testColl2.Add(testColl1[i]);
}
```

Where testColl1 is the source & testColl2 is the desired truncated collection of count = newLength.

I have used the following linq queries, but none of them are working ...

```
var result = from t in testColl1 where t.Count() <= newLength select t;
            var res = testColl1.Where(t => t.Count() <= newLength);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable.Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx):

```
var testColl2 = testColl1.Take(newLength).ToList();
```

Note that there's a semantic difference between your `for` loop and the version using `Take`. The `for` loop will throw with `IndexOutOfRangeException` exception if there are less than `newLength` items in `testColl1`, whereas the `Take` version will silently ignore this fact and just return as many items up to `newLength` items.

Comment: Ya, U are correct, by mistake I ve used +1, so edited my question. Thx

Comment: Appending .ToList() or .ToArray() at the end is not helpful in converting an IEnumerable to a collection. Is it a good practice to use like testColl2 = (Collection<string>) testColl1.Take(newLength);

Comment: @Biki: What are you talking about? Your suggestion will throw at runtime. If you insist on having an instance of `Collection<T>` (why?) you need to say `testColl2 = new Collection<string>(testColl1.Take(newLength).ToList());`. You can not cast the result of `.Take<T>` directly` to an instance of `Collection<T>`. You have to call `ToList` and pass that to the constructor of `Collection<T>`.

Comment: @Biki: Then declare it as a `IEnumerable<T>` and move on.

Comment: +1 for explaining the semantic difference between the two approaches

Answer (score 2):

The correct way is by using [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx):

```
var result = testColl1.Take(newLength);
```

An equivalent way using [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where) is:

```
var result = testColl1.Where((i, item) => i < newLength);
```

These expressions will produce an `IEnumerable`, so you might also want to attach a `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` at the end.

Both ways return one less item than your original implementation does because it is more natural (e.g. if `newLength == 0` no items should be returned).

Comment: Thanks & +1 for the where equivalent. It would be great if you can explain the where clause too.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert to `for` loop to something like this:

```
testColl1.Take(newLength)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx):

```
var result = testColl1.Take(newLength);
```

This extension method returns the first N elements from the collection where N is the parameter you pass, in this case `newLength`.